# Is it grammatically possible to change the result clause in a conditional sentence to a participle clause?

Tags: conditionals, sentence-patterns, participles

Please consider the sentence below:

> Parents have the same role in doing the household chores if both of them work.

Now I turn the first part into a participle clause while adding another sentence between the result and if clause, like:

> While having the same role in doing household chores, parents can teach their children if both of them work.

Is the sentence above **grammatically** correct? If so, is the **punctuation** correct?

**NOTE:** **Please don't look at the sentence from the perspective of meaning, for example, why do use "work" or "teach" or anything else?**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I don't see how the perspective of meaning can be avoided. You've changed from 'A, if B' to '...; C, if B'. is an 'even' or 'still' required?

Comment: I don't think you can say "don't look at the sentence from the perspective of meaning". The scope of the *if* clause is unclear. Do you want the sentence to say that if the parents don't both work, then they cannot teach their children?

Comment: On the other hand, you can construct parallel sentences which are grammatical and make sense: *While walking on a flat surface, Joe can also chew gum if he doesn't get distracted.* So *YES*, the grammar and the punctuation are correct. But that's less important than making sure that the sentence *means* what you want it to.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks, please put forward your last comment as an answer; I will accept it. I did not set my original sentence, here.

Comment: The question is essentially no more than proofreading, which is off topic. (And the first half of the question is irrelevant to any answer if meaning is ruled out.) It's like asking if you can change the sentence *See Jane run.* to *John is a fast runner.* Of course you can, and it's grammatical. But the first sentence has little to do with the second sentence in terms of meaning. Yes, you can change it. But not without changing the meaning.

Comment: While I commend your motive for wanting to "beef up"  your paper, I cannot help but comment on the meaning of the sentence as you've laid it out. I am not a grammarian and am not, therefore, conversant in "conditionals" and "participles." The point I think you are trying to make is this: "When both working parents do household chores, they set a good example for their children." If I'm wrong, well, forgive me. Don

Comment: The second sentence is also phrased in a way that raises the question of whether it is the parents or the children who work, regardless of how unlikely the latter case may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can say "don't look at the sentence from the perspective of meaning". The scope of the if clause is unclear. Do you really want the sentence to say that if the parents don't both work, then they cannot teach their children?

On the other hand, you can construct parallel sentences which are grammatical and make sense: *While walking on a flat surface, Joe can also chew gum if he doesn't get distracted.* So **yes**, the grammar and the punctuation are correct. But that's less important than making sure that the sentence means what you want it to.